# Running a TV with raspberry pi 3

Tags: pi-3, video

Can a raspberry pi 3 handle running video on a large TV (50-90inch)? It's very important that the resolution and refresh rate is good. It can't look choppy and laggy. Does the raspberry pi 3 have the specs for this?

Comment: What's the quality of the content you intend to watch and is it streamed or local files?

Answer (score 1):

The best information I can find suggests that it's possible to output 4K resolutions, but at fairly miserable frame rates. The Pi 3 has the same GPU as the Pi 2, so the information should still be valid:

Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=79330

I did actually connected my raspberry pi 3 to a big TV screen and it worked fine, so you should not have problem until it is not 4k or hyper resolution with an high framerate.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi supports 1080p@30 fps **if** the source is encoded with h.264. All other resolutions , framerates and codecs are not always guaranteed to be usable. For example , only the Pi3 with Kodi supports
h.265 , but not in 4K at all.